# Is loading several packages in the same cell safe, or it may cause probems?

Tags: packages, kernel, kernel-startup

My Mathematica 13.3 crashed after working 30 minutes. It produced a beep and no output. After that, it lost the capability of loading packages. I will reinstall it now. I wonder  if this happened to other users, and whether there is any advice on how to deal with this, short of reinstalling

Reinstalling hasn't fixed the problem. In fact, as suggested by @MarcoB, everything was due to my initial cell in which I had added loading a  forth   package, maybe with a syntax error (an extra ;). This first cell is rather 'finicky'. Sometimes, after an incorrect syntax modification, it fails even after the error is corrected. Then, loading restarts working only  if the packages
are loaded in separate cells. Now I managed, loading first two

```
ClearAll["Global\[OpenCurlyQuote]*"]
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
Needs["ReactionKinetics`"];(*<<chemJac.wl;*)
<< epid`; ?"epid`*"
```

and then other two .mx files

```
<< fi2`
<< re21`
```

So, the question was resolved empirically, but I do not understand why if there is one syntax error, loading does not resume, even after the error is corrected.

Comment: I assume you have restarted your computer. Can you also include the code you are using to load the packages?

Comment: Thanks, this was indeed the problem, as detailed now in the modified question.